issue with my 36h/36nh adapter on ubuntu 20.04
I have 2 network adapters, one says alfa awus 036nh on it and the other with 036h
If I run lsusb I get the same output for both of them:
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter

When I use wireshark on ubuntu 20.04(also tried on kali but the same) my adapter fails to capture some of the authentication 802.11 frames from my phone to my Access Point.
I searched a bit and on this thread seems a similar issue, and the person says he found out it is a driver issue.
I ran lsmod as my adapter is plugged to see the drives available on my ubuntu 20.04. I got this part of output which is eyecatching:
Module                  Size  Used by

r8188eu               692224  0
nfnetlink_queue        24576  0
nfnetlink_log          20480  0
nfnetlink              20480  2 nfnetlink_queue,nfnetlink_log
rtl8187                53248  0
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rtl8187

so I have 2 drivers for realtek devices, r8188eu and r8187 yet they are not used, and some chipset driver named eeprom_93cx6 is used by my rtl8187 it seems.. This is supposed to be not right, correct ? If so, how can I switch to make my usb adapter to use the rtl8187 for example? So I can test packet capture with that driver to see if I run into any issues.. Or what would be correct driver usage or correct way of doing this?
Extra command, if helps:
root@ubuntu-ThinkPad:/home/ubuntu# lsmod | grep rtl8187
rtl8187                53248  0
mac80211             1249280  2 iwlmvm,rtl8187
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rtl8187
cfg80211              970752  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,rtl8187

Update:
Or maybe my question wrong, my adapter already users rtl8187, yet rtl8187 module uses eeprom_93cx6. So a module uses another module. Yet I don't know which module my physical adapter uses then? If I could make sense?
Apparently yes. I got the whole thing wrong. Module structure is like a tree. Module can be used by another module and another module. My adapter apparently uses rtl8187
I ran lsusb -t to check:
  |__ Port 4: Dev 15, If 0, Class=, Driver=rtl8187, 480M

Now here is my question, How can I change the driver a usb adapter already uses then ?
